# Github Autolink reference to Agile Accelerator work

Tags: github

I would like to add a an autolink reference rule to my Github repository, in order to generate direct links to Agile Accelerator works automatically.

Is there any way or practical workaround, to have urls ponting to works using a link with only the work ID (W-00XXXX) as param ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom Visualforce page that take a URL parameter, e.g the Work Id, then use the Work Id to retrieve the Salesforce record.

See this blog post for example code: https://www.davehelgerson.com/url-parameters-within-apex-and-visualforce/